# Visual Studio 2010 Extension for grouping files into folders

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-extensions

I'm looking for an Extension that allows me to group Files into Virtual folders.

Example:

I have a Solution with 3 Projects. UI (MVC), Security Layer, BusinessLayer/DAL.

Each of the 3 Projects have some classes/views that handles stuff for let's say "User Management":

- UI : Views, Controller, ViewModels
- Security Layer: Security Checks
- BL/DAL: Business Logic, Data Access

What I want is an Extension like a "Logical Solution Explorer" where I can create Virtual Folders in it and put links to all "User Management" classes/views in it.

Is there something like that available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I really like the Favorite Documents extension.  It sounds like it could help.  You can find more information about it at: http://www.svprogramming.net/favorite-documents/